# Sum variables in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have found myself into an issue that looked so simple and stupid at the beginning but keeps me struggling to solve it for over 24 hours now.

I have a string (bunch of numbers delimited by |) that I want to be converted into array and then sum some of the array keys depending on the case.

The first issue I have found was the Integer length limitation, I couldn't believe when VBA was unable to return a number higher than 32767 (Then I found longs...). After "solving" that I found that when trying to SUM some 0 values it actually increase my grand total and I can't find any explanation for this.

Below you can see what I have now:

```
Public Function calcTime(TimeType As String)
Dim jsSting As String
Dim strSplit As Variant
Dim tempTime as Double

jsSting = "100|0|10080|400|0|4320|70|0|1440|30|0|2280|10|0|7400|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|300|0|15855|90|0|1721"
'Split the string by delimiter
strSplit = Split(jsSting, "|")


Select Case UCase(TimeType)
    Case "TOTAL"
        tempTime = WorksheetFunction.Sum(strSplit(2), strSplit(5), strSplit(8), strSplit(11), strSplit(14), strSplit(17), strSplit(20), strSplit(23), strSplit(26), strSplit(29), strSplit(32), strSplit(35), strSplit(38))
    Case "GROUP1" ' Team 1 + Team2
        tempTime = WorksheetFunction.Sum(strSplit(2), strSplit(5), strSplit(8), strSplit(11), strSplit(14))
    Case "GROUP2" ' Team 1 + Team2 + Team3 
        tempTime = WorksheetFunction.Sum(strSplit(2), strSplit(5), strSplit(8), strSplit(11), strSplit(14), strSplit(38))
    Case "GROUP3" ' Team 5
        tempTime = WorksheetFunction.Sum(strSplit(17), strSplit(20), strSplit(23), strSplit(26))
    Case "GROUP4" ' Team 2
        tempTime = strSplit(14)
    Case "GROUP5" ' Team 6
        tempTime = WorksheetFunction.Sum(strSplit(29), strSplit(32), strSplit(35))
End Select

Return tempTime
End Function
```

In this example I have tried to use Excel's SUM function in order to get the desired result but It wasn't a success.

Sticking to the TOTAL case. It sums the following keys - values:

```
jsString(2)  - 10080
jsString(5)  - 4320
jsString(8)  - 1440
jsString(11) - 2280
jsString(14) - 7400
jsString(17) - 0
jsString(20) - 0
jsString(23) - 0
jsString(26) - 0
jsString(29) - 0
jsString(32) - 0
jsString(35) - 15855
jsString(38) - 0
```

This gives a total of 41375, however, when I do the sum in VBA I get 43096 and I can't understand why. If I remove from the SUM the values with 0 it returns the correct 41k value.

Hope this makes sense and the answer is simple (I am seriously thinking that I've missed something when assigning the data type).

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: I think in your select case you meant to write `strSplit` rather than `JsSting`, but that's not the problem I've realized after.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it. Type generated because I have replaced the variable names (internal stuff issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you maybe mean ... ?

```
Select Case UCase(TimeType)
Case "TOTAL"
    tempTime = WorksheetFunction.Sum(strSplit(2), strSplit(5), strSplit(8), strSplit(11), strSplit(14), strSplit(17), strSplit(20), strSplit(23), strSplit(26), strSplit(29), strSplit(32), strSplit(35), strSplit(38)
```

Anyway, the problem is that you're summing also `strSplit(38)` which is 1721 even if you wrote in your sample which is equal to 0, exactly the difference between Excel and VBA ;)

Check with a `MsgBox strSplit(38)` in your code.

Comment: Feeling so stupid now. I have made a DEBUG MSGBox that sums everything and used 28 intead of 38. Thank you very much !

Comment: I bet every developer has spent at least a week of his life in mistakes like this, don't worry ;)

Answer (score 0):

strsplit(38) = 1721, which is the difference of 43096  and 41375

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I beg to differ. He asked why his VBA code and adding in Excel made a difference. He assumed that jsString(38) was 0, while it was actually 1721, which exactly equals said difference.

Comment: ...and all of this could go into a comment.

Comment: Why put it in a comment when it is meant to answer his question? A discussion about what qualifies as an answer and what doesnt't could rage on forever and seems quite pointless to me, so I will leave it at this.

Comment: Yes, it is pointless, and it wouldn't have been even started, if someone had read the wiki and FAQ.